# GROUP BY doesn't contain specific column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following statement in MSSQL

```
SELECT a, b, MAX(t)
FROM table
GROUP BY a, b
```

What I want is just to show c and d columns for each specific row in the result. How can I do that?

Comment: A bit of sample data would help.

Comment: Which values of `c` and `d` do you want to show for a group? Remember, a group will have multiple underlying rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) or [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) (the former will ignore ties, the latter will include them), something like:

```
;With Ranked as (
    SELECT a,b,c,d,t,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a,b
                             ORDER BY t desc) as rn
    FROM table
)
SELECT * from Ranked where rn = 1
```

Which will return one row for each unique combination of the `a,b` columns, choosing the other values such that they come from the row with the highest `t` value (and, as I say, this variant ignores ties).

Comment: Did you mean to put `;` instead of `:` before `WITH` ?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos -yes, I did.